# vb.NET WebRequest to read aspx page to string, access denied?

Tags: html, vb.net, parsing, asp.net, webrequest

I'm trying to make an executable in VS2008 that will read a webpage source code using a vb.NET function into a string variable. The problem is that the page is not *.html but rather *.aspx.

I need a way to execute the aspx and get the displayed html into a string.

The page I want to read is any page of this type: http://www.realtor.ca/PropertyDetails.aspx?PropertyID=9620716

I have tried the following code, which works properly for html pages, but generates the wrong source code with "access denied" for the page title when I pass in the above aspx page.

```
    Dim myReq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)

    Dim myWebResponse As WebResponse = myReq.GetResponse()

    Dim dataStream As Stream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream()

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Could you post the code that creates the `url` variable?

Answer (score 1):

I get the same thing while running wget from the command line:

```
wget http://www.realtor.ca/PropertyDetails.aspx?PropertyID=9620716
```

I guess the server is relying on that something is set in the browser before the response is delivered, e.g. a cookie. You might want to try using a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control (you don't have to have it visible) in the following way (this works):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf DocumentCompletedHandler)
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.realtor.ca/PropertyDetails.aspx?PropertyID=9620716")
    End Sub

    Private Sub DocumentCompletedHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine(WebBrowser1.DocumentText)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work!  I think you are right about needing a cookie or something. I can look into that. Thanks for the help, the WebBrowser DocumentText idea will work great. Cheers

Comment: If this answer is acceptable, please mark it as your accepted answer so that the responder gets credit for his/ her assistance.